# Setup USB Flash Drive as Physical Security Key on Windows

Tags: windows-10, usb-flash-drive, login, login-screen

I am trying to change the security of my system to a physical device(with a password backup) mode, and have a very long password which I need not use every single time to login since I possess the physical key myself.

Windows provides an option to do this with its Security Key feature in the Windows Settings
[image]

However as I checked, this is allowed only for physical security devices which are special hardware. I do not have any such hardware, and the cost is just way too much for me to afford one.

I found this application [USB Raptor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/usbraptor/) which is basically a software does something similar, it constantly monitors the presence of a file on a prespecified USB stick. However this is a very heavy software, with significant memory usage (~100 MB) and processor usage (~0.6%) which is way too much for  my requirement. Also it locks me out even after startup if I remove the USB drive, and I have to manually shut it down myself every single time after login. Which again brings issues like sometimes not starting up at boot time, and not being active after a sleep/hibernate when the lock screen appears

What I am looking for is a way to be able to use a USB flash drive as a security key only during Login. Once logged in, I should not be logged out of the system for removing the USB(as the aforementioned USB raptor does). And preferably something which uses low memory and processor. And shuts down once the login is complete. And should accept my USB flash drive after hibernate/sleep.

Comment: Try [this](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/how-to-use-phone-lock-unlock-windows-10,36775.html)

Comment: Security Key in this instance is talking about compatible YubiKey devices